# Will a neodymium magnet levitate on ice at Earth's North and South Pole?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, magnetic-fields, earth, geomagnetism

Will a neodymium magnet levitate on ice at NP or SP? Asking just because these magnets are powerful and the Earth magnetism is fairly stronger at poles than at the Equator.

Comment: The magnetic field is only about 2x stronger at the poles.  So thus, for a magnet to levetate at the pole, it must have at least half its weight in magnetic forces at any arbitrary place in the world (like your desk).  If you swung a neodyimium magnet around, you would feel it.

Comment: Stronger than not much at all is still not much.